# How to define <p:calendar> pattern to entire application?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to define the p:calendar pattern to the entire application instead of to put pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" in each p:calendar.

Comment: you can create composite component or custom tag with default pattern value

Answer (score 0):

What I did was overload the renderer for the calendar component with my own and set it there.